# Finding number of orbits and cardinality of each orbit

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let G be a group of order 15 action on a set X of cardinality 17. Suppose that for all x ∈ X, we have $|O_x| ≥ 2$. Determine the number of orbits and the cardinality of each orbit.

With a given lemma, I know that $|X| = \sum_{distinct orbits O_x} |O_x|$, so I get $17 =\sum_{distinct orbits O_x} |O_x|$, and because $|O_x| \geq 2$, I know that $|O_x| \in \{3,5,15 \}$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: You solve the equation. There is only one solution in this case.

Comment: Can you let me now how you conclude that $|O_x| \in \{3,5,15 \}$

Comment: Now I figure it out that you use Lagrange's theorem and the orbit-stabilizer theorem with the fact that $|O_x| \geq 2$ to conclude that $|O_x| \in \{3,5,15\}$

Answer (score 1):

The following equation must be solved for nonnegative integers $n,m,k$:$$3n+5m+15k=17$$

And it is almost immediate that $k=0$ is the only option here, so we get:$$3n+5m=17$$

Now just solve that by checking the possibilities one by one.

Comment: i am beginner in group theory and i ask it to be sure. So , can we say that there are $8$ orbits because $3+5=8$. Moreover , three of of thoso orbits have $4$ cardinality and $5$ orbits have only one elements ,i.e, 5 orbits have cardinality $1$ . Is my answer true ?

Comment: @leonard No. In the question it is stated already that only the numbers $3,5,15$ are canditates for orbit-cardinalities. In my answer I state that $k=0$ which means that orbits with cardinality $15$ do not exist. From equation $3n+5m=17$ we find easily that $n=4$ and $m=1$. This all means that there are $4$ orbits of cardinality $3$ and there is $1$ orbit of cardinality $5$.